# Stop watching the output of a particular program after using watch command?

Tags: linux, watch

I have come to know that we can use `watch` command to monitor the output of other command and it prints the output every 2 seconds by default, which is really useful.

I start to use it to monitor the output of `nvidia-smi`, for example. But now I do not know how to quit the program (stop monitoring the output of `nvidia-smi`). I tried to press `q` and there is no response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `man watch`:

> By default, watch will run until interrupted.

The key words are "until interrupted", which basically can be interpreted as until (but not limited to) the following happening:

- The user (you) pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal.
- The system restarted.
- The process was issued a `kill` request.

Comment: I am curious to know why there is no shortcut to use `q` to stop watching, just like when we are using `less` or `man` command. A lot of command support the use of `q` to quit.

Comment: I am not one of the programmers and I can not answer for them. As far as I understand, the source code for `watch` is available and you should be able to either fork it and create your own version that includes the option to press `Q` to quit or extend it like others have by submitting a patch or getting directly involved in the program development.

Comment: @Hao, note that reacting to a signal (generated by Ctrl+C) and reading tokens from `stdin` are very different code paths.  `less` and `man` accept a variety of keystroke commands; `q` is just another among several.  `watch` accepts no keystroke commands, so it would be functionality added only for quit.

Answer (score 2):

Press **CRTL+C** to stop the command